# Is there a way to make a display window in python?

Tags: python

I’m just starting to learn python and we have to do a coding assigment in school. There a few examples of problems you can do , or you can create your own, but i want use one of the examples. i want to know if theres a way to create a seperate display window in python to display images for a game. Ive seen tutorials using “pygame” but we’re not allowed to download anything onto the school computers so i cant use any add-ons. Ive only been learning very basic stuff thats entirely text based.

Comment: Maybe [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html)?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle for a local web app?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Tkinter. It comes with Python so you should not need to download anything.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-gui-tkinter/

Comment: thank you so much! this is exactly the kind of thing i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I've had a pretty good experience using [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home). It's easier to learn than Tkinter, in my opinion, though it's possibly less flexible.

Comment: Kivy requires installation. It does not ship with the default Python.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Ah, I see. I missed that in the question.